# oracle select aplhanumeric value from the column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In oracle I have a table teststring and column name is `STRINGVALUE` and values in the column are :

```
A1CC
A2BB
C1DD
C2CC
ABA28
1B333
AB345
1A222
2NDDD
```

I have to select only those value which has first 2 values alphanumeric like `A1CC`,`A2BB`,`1B33`,`2NDDD` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT stringvalue FROM teststring
  WHERE regexp_like(substr(stringvalue,1,2),'[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z]');
```

or

```
SELECT stringvalue FROM teststring
  WHERE regexp_like(substr(stringvalue,1,2),'[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]');
```

Answer (score 0):

> select only those value which has first 2 values alphanumeric

Your example output doesn't satisfy the rule you mentioned. According to your rule, this is the test case :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'A1CC' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'A2BB' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'C1DD' str from dual union all
  5  SELECT 'C2CC' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'ABA28' str from dual union all
  7  SELECT '1B333' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'AB345' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9  SELECT '1A222' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10  SELECT '2NDDD' FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT STR
 12  FROM DATA
 13  WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,1,1),'[[:alpha:]]')
 14  AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,2,1),'[[:digit:]]'))
 15  OR (REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,1,1),'[[:digit:]]')
 16  AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,2,1),'[[:alpha:]]'))
 17  /

STR
-----
A1CC
A2BB
C1DD
C2CC
1B333
1A222
2NDDD

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lalit, when i was using regular expression i was missing the keyword digit thats why i was unable to get the right result set.
in my requirement i have more than thousand value in that column so simply i have called the calum name from the table instead of using the dual union and its working fine..
the new query where any number of record available in the column below format would be feasible.

```
 WITH DATA AS(SELECT STRINGVALUE as STR FROM TESTSTRING )
  SELECT STR
  FROM DATA
  WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,1,1),'[[:alpha:]]')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,2,1),'[[:digit:]]'))
  OR (REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,1,1),'[[:digit:]]')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(STR,2,1),'[[:alpha:]]'))
```

Comment: That is why I always insist to post a working test case with any SQL question. i had to manually build a test case for you. Also, if you are satisfied with the answer, you can vote it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query

```
with TAB(TXT) as(
  select 'A1CC' from dual union all
  select 'A2BB' from dual union all
  select 'C1DD' from dual union all
  select 'C2CC' from dual union all
  select 'ABA28' from dual union all
  select '1B333' from dual union all
  select 'AB345' from dual union all
  select '1A222' from dual union all
  select '2NDDD' from dual)
----------------
--- End of Data 
----------------  
select txt
  from tab
 where (regexp_like(TXT, '^((\w\d)|(\d\w)){1}\w+'));
```

To get output like:

```
|   TXT |
|-------|
|  A1CC |
|  A2BB |
|  C1DD |
|  C2CC |
| 1B333 |
| 1A222 |
| 2NDDD |
```